How to find the URL for an answer
I used to be able to obtain the URL for an answer, or a comment, by right-clicking on the relevant timestamp and choosing "Copy Link". For answers, that doesn't work for me now. However, it works fine for comments. When I right-click the timestamp for an answer (or anywhere else on the answer that I have tried so far), in the drop-down context menu, there is no option for "Copy Link"
Am I missing something ?
How do I find the URL for an answer ?

Click on the "Share" link.

@whuber thanks, but I've tried that several times, both left (just brings up a message saying that it's been saved) and right (no option to "Copy Link")

There must be a problem at your end, then, because this has unfailingly worked for me from the beginning and as recently as when I posted my earlier comment.  In fact, I don't recognize your description, because the message I get upon clicking "share" and then "copy link" in the pop-up dialog is "Link copied to clipboard."

@camhsdoc If you don't see the same thing as whuber mentions in his answer below, check if you have some browser extension that could interfere with the proper functioning of the website. I remember that I had to tweak a bit the "NoScript" extension in Firefox for the "share" feature to work.

The posted comment / answer is correct.  In the sort term, if there is a problem with your browser & you can't fix it, you can navigate to the answerer's userpage, go to their answers, find the link to that answer, & right-click copy link.

These options appear below answers:

Clicking "Share" raises this dialog:

The URL is pre-selected so you can copy it (Ctrl-C on Windows machines, for instance).  Alternatively, click on the "Copy link" option.  Success is indicated by a message at the top of the screen, "Link copied to clipboard."  Paste it anywhere you like.
